# Deleting data from SQLite database on device

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing UAT testing and need to wipe the data off my phone.. not my emulator an actual phone which I've installed the app on so that I can reinstall the app.. my app has a register activity that only runs if the database isn't present in other words the first time the app is run. Is there a way to access existing SQLite db's on the phone itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Android Settings->Apps->"Your App", and then click the Clear Data button.  This will delete any data associated with the app including the database.  If you rerun the app, then no database will be present.

Answer (score 4):

To clear app data very quickly, use a adb + pm command.  From terminal (or command prompt),

```
adb shell pm clear your.app.package
```

This will work on most modern devices (I have one shitty OG samsung tab on android 2.2 where it doesn't,  but works on all my others).

As a plus, in case you ever want to uninstall,

```
adb uninstall your.app.package
```